# Concatenation error in recursive function with a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, recursion, tuples, concatenation

I currently have this recursive one-liner utilizing a list comprehension

```
def f(n):
    return 1 if n == 1 else min([2 * f(n - x) + (2 ** x) - 1 for x in range(1, n)])
```

As you can see it returns the minimum int from a list of ints generated using the function in the range (1 <= x < n) however I would like this list comprehension to return the minimum TUPLE as follows:

```
def f(n):
    return 1 if n == 1 else min([(2 * f(n - x) + (2 ** x) - 1, x) for x in range(1, n)])
```

So I can see which which x value the minimum value belongs to, however if I do this it generates the following error:

```
builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

And I cant understand nor see where it is trying to concatenate an int despite my attempts at debugging and crafting similar functions (non-recursive but they work).
Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a tuple in the list comprehension, but you haven't adjusted the rest of the code to handle tuples. In particular, this part:

```
return 1 if n == 1
```

isn't returning a tuple, and this part:

```
2 * f(n - x) + (2 ** x) - 1
```

is trying to do math with the return value of `f`, forgetting that the return value is a tuple instead of a number.

Comment: Gosh, of course it had to be this big of an oversight. Anyways, I managed to get it working, thank you!